# Подсчитать количество в записе

Tags: php, mysql

В базе хранится записи (друзья пользователя) в виде:

```
qwerty1,qwerty2
```

Это массив, который хранит в себе пользователей. Как подсчитать количество пользователей в нем?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно так попробовать:

```
$friends = "f1,f2,f3";
$countFriends = count(explode(',', $friends));
echo $countFriends;
```

Comment: именно этим вариантом и воспользовался

Comment: @LLIAKAJI, там слева есть кнопочка для того, чтобы принять ответ

Answer (score 0):

Можно так: у нас есть строка через запятые, значит кол-во слов это кол-во запятых + 1

Вот реализация

```
len(value) - len(replace(value,',','')) + 1
```

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined function len()

Comment: @LLIAKAJI - ох.., ну из контекста же понятно что речь о [strlen()][1]

[1]: http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.strlen.php

Comment: проблема решилась вот таким вот образом 
переменная= explode(',',значение);
echo count(переменная);